# UPS for WiFi router (automatic switching between battery and DC adapter )

Tags: switching, ups, router

I want to make a UPS for a WiFi router. Following is the schematic I am thinking to implement.

My idea is to implement the following:

1. The input DC adapter will provide power to the two converter modules as well as charge the battery pack. The BMS will take care of all the battery protection.
2. When there is a power failure, the MOSFET will turn on and power will flow to the converter modules from the battery pack.

I am worried about the diode D3. Is it the right position in the circuit? I have used it to ensure that when the MOSFET is on, power should not flow to the adapter.

Any improvement suggestions are highly appreciated.

This is the continuation of my following project
https://youtu.be/C8EERXAAnas

[image]

Comment: There's no schematic.

Comment: I don't see any battery charging circuit. A BMS is NOT a charger.